# Scala - read JSON file as a single String with Spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have JSON files describing a table structure. I want to read each file from S3 as a single String in order to then apply a `fromJson()` method of `apache.spark.sql.types.DataType`

```
DataType.fromJson(jsonString).asInstanceOf[StructType]
```

But for now I only managed to read the files into a DataFrame:

```
 val testJsonData = sqlContext.read.option("multiline", "true").json("/s3Bucket/metrics/metric1.json")
```

But I don't need a `df.schema`, instead I need to parse the contents of a JSON string to a StructType.

The contents of a JSON file:

```
{
  "type" : "struct",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "metric_name",
    "type" : "string",
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { }
  }, {
    "name" : "metric_time",
    "type" : "long",
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { }
  }, {
    "name" : "metric_value",
    "type" : "string",
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { }
  }]
}
```

Comment: this might help https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/transform-complex-data-types-scala.html

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you want to use is [`sc.wholeTextFiles`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#wholeTextFiles-java.lang.String-int-) (sc is a `SparkContext` in this case).

This results in an `RDD[(String, String)]` where `._1` is the file name, and `._2` is the entire file content. Maybe you can try:

```
val files = sc.wholeTextFiles("/s3Bucket/metrics/", 16).toDS()
files.map(DataType.fromJson(_._2).asInstanceOf[StructType])
```

Which, in theory, would give you an `Dataset[StructType]`. Unfortunately, I'm not finding a similar function in the pure spark sql API, but this may work.